# Swift, change image memory footprint

Tags: ios, swift, image

My app downloads images from web site. How can I scale and change each image's memory footprint? I have a preview gallery, when I load 40-50 photos the RAM increases up to 800-900MB and the app crashes.

Or I should use flash memory to save these photos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of set size of image you should set size of UIImageView and then put this image on it so, size of image will be display as per your requirement.

```
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150)); // set as you want
    var image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png");
    imageView.image = image;
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```